# How to know if the button state has changed from enabled to disabled android?

Tags: android, components

I am creating a custom button which is going to be exposed for usage.
I want to change the color of the button depending on the state(if its enabled or disable).programatically.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to set its drawable to be a StateListDrawable which has the different enabled and disabled states embedded in it.  Then you don't need to set it, it will set itself.

Comment: Yes that's what I was thinking. I see the state android.R.attr.state_enabled but there is no disabled state attr.

Comment: Oh actually I just saw that I can use {- R.att.state_enabled} to indicate disabled state

Answer (score 0):

If you want create a custom button, you could do like this:

```
public class CustomBtn extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton {
    private Context context;

    public CustomBtn(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public CustomBtn(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public CustomBtn(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        super.setEnabled(enabled);
        if (enabled) {
            this.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
        } else {
            this.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        }
    }
}
```

and use the custom button as below:

```
CustomBtn customBtn = findViewById(R.id.customBtn); //add a CustomBtn like normal widget in layout xml
customBtn.setEnabled(true);//this button color will be R.color.colorPrimary
customBtn.setEnabled(false);//this button color will be R.color.colorPrimaryDark
```